# How to go through a given key list when using CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (...) WITH (key)?

Tags: json, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #Keys (k NVARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO #Keys VALUES ('key1'), ('key2'), ('key3');

CREATE TABLE #Data ( v NVARCHAR(MAX) )
INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES ( N'{"key1":{"1":{}},"key2":{"1":{}}}' )

SELECT *
FROM #Data J
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.v) WITH (key1 NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) key1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.v) WITH (key2 NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) key2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.v) WITH (key3 NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) key3
```

How do I go through the fields from #keys instead of hardcoding them in CROSS APPLY?

Expected Result:

```
key1     | key2     | key3  
{"1":{}} | {"1":{}} | NULL
```

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I don't think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes when accessing fields with invalid JSON names, such as when fields begin/end with a number.  Otherwise, there is no way to flatten the data by simply saying 'select * from nested_json.'

```
SELECT *, 
  JSON_VALUE(key1.key1, '$."1"') jv1,
  JSON_VALUE(key2.key2, '$."1"') jv2,
  JSON_VALUE(key3.key3, '$') jv3
FROM #Data J
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.v) WITH (key1 NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) key1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.v) WITH (key2 NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) key2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.v) WITH (key3 NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) key3;
```

EDIT: To join between #Keys.k and j.[Key] the collation must be the same.  Here I switched in the DDL for #Keys to Latin1_General_BIN2.

```
CREATE TABLE #Keys (k NVARCHAR(10) collate Latin1_General_BIN2);
INSERT INTO #Keys VALUES ('key1'), ('key2'), ('key3');

CREATE TABLE #Data ( v NVARCHAR(MAX) )
INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES ( N'{"key1":{"1":{}},"key2":{"1":{}}}' )

SELECT *
FROM
  #Data J
 CROSS APPLY
  OPENJSON(J.v) oj
 join
  #Keys k on oj.[key]=k.k;
```

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I would like to somehow use the #keys table with CROSS APPLY. So, instead of hardcoding "key1" I would like to use #keys.k field value. @SteveC